# Complete ordered space

Tags: general-topology, complete-spaces, order-topology

In their paper [A Method for Constructing Ordered Continua](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0166864185900562/1-s2.0-0166864185900562-main.pdf?_tid=236bb7b2-84d1-11e6-bfef-00000aab0f6b&acdnat=1474994625_18abb742f05ad9500fdeb28a5a0c87e1) , Hart and van Mill give the following definition of **ordered continuum**:

> An *ordered continuum* is a compact, connected linearly ordered topological space, equivalently, a complete and densely linearly ordered set equipped with the order topology.

My question is a about the word *complete*.

I know that a linearly ordered space is *connected* if and only if it is densely ordered and *Dedekind complete* (every non empty subset that is bounded above admits a supremum). But that is not enough for this definition.

So I think that *complete* here means *complete lattice* (every subset has both supremum and infimum), as complete lattices are compact. Is that correct?

If it is, I have another question. Is completeness as a lattice equivalent to completeness in the sense of uniformity (in case the space is indeed uniformizable)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, "complete" here means "complete as a lattice".  Alternatively, it just means the variant of Dedekind-complete where you require that *any* set has a supremum (without requiring the set to be nonempty or bounded).

Completeness in this sense is not equivalent to completeness with respect to a uniformity.  For instance, $\mathbb{R}$ is complete with its standard uniformity, but is not complete as an ordered set in this sense.